# Broken pip3 in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, python, ubuntu-mate, pip

When i run `pip3`, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

I'm running python2.7 and python3.6.3 on my Ubuntu Mate.

pip2(pip) works fine but pip3 is broken.

How do I fix it?

Comment: If there is a longer error message, what is the full error that you get when you run `pip3` ? Please use the edit link under your question to edit it into your question.

Comment: duplicate with https://askubuntu.com/questions/998437/pip3-missing-dependency Try to reinstall `setuptools`.